# How translate netbeans UI into a IDE-free UI?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have to work on a tool developed in Java, on Netbeans.
I had previously several problems related to the Netbeans version. (I update my Netbeans version to 8.XX and the executable wouldn't work because it was developed in 7.XX)

Is it possible to convert this code in a IDE free code ? Which library would be use ? Or is it possible to "extract" the UI components from Net beans ?
...or is it too much work ?

Comment: The best way is not to use the NetBeans editor. The code it generates is crappy anyway.

Comment: Are you perhaps saying that you are using the Netbeans platform to build your UI, rather than standard Swing or JavaFX code?

Comment: No, the app is already developed, not by me and I have to implement some changes into it. Because I struggle to make it work, because of the Netbeans related thing, I wanted to evaluate the work needed get the UI out of Netbeans. In the end, the only thing preventing me from freeing the code from Netbeans is the UI.

Comment: UI isn't normally dependent on IDE. Does your UI use JavaFX or Swing? Do you build using ANT or maven? If you have ANT or Maven you can usually build from the command line

Comment: Also, in Netbeans you can set the Java version of your project using the Project Properties tab. It is not necessary yo update the version of Netbeans. If you have Netbeans 8, you can still build projects based on earlier versions of Java